# PhoneGap for Android deviceready not working

Tags: cordova

Problem is 'deviceready' event is not firing. Example app that comes with cordova works and I can copy it and create from there. But I need to know what is going wrong. I have tried everything (you can see the commented code). few important things.

1. I created the project from here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android.
2. I am using Jquery mobile and it is working fine.
3. whole project is here http://www.filefactory.com/file/1pseohvngmuz/n/HelloCordova_zip

   ```
   /*************************************************************
   function init() {
       alert('init');
   }


   $(function() {
       alert('load');
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
         alert("123");
    },false);
   });

   $(document).ready(function(e) {
   });

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
   function onDeviceReady()
   {
       alert('Phonegap ready');
   }
   ********************************************/
   function init() {

       document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceInfo, false);
   }
   var deviceInfo = function() {
       alert('PhoneGap ready');
   };
   </script>
   ```

Thank you very much..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found the bug myself. the cordova script file name was 'cordova-1.8.1.js'. while I was including 'cordova-1.8.0.js'  and it took me two days to find it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to get deviceready with jQM

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        alert("PhoneGap is now loaded!");
    }, false);
}, false);
```

Comment: Simon.. first the code you pasted should work then I can think about using JQuery mobile. Please check the project files. It is just not a usual problem. thank you.